# How much bits will this tree structure use?

Tags: java, tree, bit

```
class TreeNode{
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
}
TreeNode t = new TreeNode(4);
t.left = new TreeNode(3);
t.right = new TreeNode(5);
```

Just wondering is it 3*32(bit) = 96? Because each integer costs 32 bit. I am not sure am I calculating right?

Comment: Are you taking into account the size of the references?

Comment: I don't know how to calculate the size of the references..... Could you help?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/209249/what-is-the-size-of-a-reference-variable-in-java-can-it-be-calculated

Answer (score 0):

This can't get an absolute answer as it depends on internal details of your current JRE, which is quite likely to change between releases.

Let's get the basics straight for some 32-Bit example JRE:

- an `int` is 4 bytes = 32 bits
- a reference is 4 bytes = 32 bits (will be longer in 64-Bit Java)
- an instance needs some header bytes (maybe 16 bytes = 128 bits) plus its fields. In some situations, the layout needs a few extra "padding" bytes.

Instances get created on the "heap", local variables on the "stack".

Based on these numbers, one `TreeNode` instance needs 224 bits:

- 128 bits instance header
- 32 bits for `val`
- 32 bits for the `left` reference
- 32 bits for the `right` reference

You create 3 `TreeNodes`, so that's 672 bytes on the heap.

In addition, you have one variable `t` on the stack, being one reference of 32 bits.

Once again, these are only example figures, it depends on the JRE version you use.